# How to setup Relay with Youshido\GraphQL server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, relayjs, relay

I have following architecture

1. GraphQL server running with Youshido\GraphQLBundle at http://localhost:5000/graphql
2. React app created by command `create-react-app my-app` also on localhost:3001

I want to setup Relay to work with graphql server but I got this error in browser console:

```
invariant.js:44 Uncaught Error: RelayQL: Unexpected invocation at runtime. Either the Babel transform was not set up, or it failed to identify this call site. Make sure it is being used verbatim as `Relay.QL`.(…)
```

I read https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-babel-plugin.html and tried to set it up

1. I've installed "babel-relay-plugin"
2. I've created build/babelRelayPlugin.js file which gets the schema from graphql into data/schema.json and schema.graphql files

**build/babelRelayPlugin.js**

```
const getBabelRelayPlugin = require('babel-relay-plugin');
const schema = require('../data/schema.json');

module.exports = getBabelRelayPlugin(schema.data);
```

3. I've created file with the following content

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [
    {
      "plugins": [
        "./build/babelRelayPlugin"
      ]
    },
    "react",
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Relay from 'react-relay';
import App from './App';
import SampleRoute from './routes/SampleRoute';
import './index.css';

Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
    new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('http://localhost:5000/graphql')
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Relay.RootContainer
        Component={App}
        route={new SampleRoute()}
    />
        ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

when I run the script it downloads schema from graphql and it seems to work. On relay side, I've created a basic route and connected component to it via basic container.

The question is what am I missing and why it still doesn't work and throw this error that babel was not set up?

I'm totally newbie with this setup so I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What error do you get on your `graphql` request in the network section of the dev tool? If it's 500 perhaps it's a cross-origin problem?

Comment: It's not .There's no XHR error. There's only one request to http://localhost:3001/sockjs-node/info?t=1487062676068 and response code is 200

Comment: How does your generated schema file look like?

Comment: By the way, if I recall correctly, Youshido doesn't seem to have support for directives such as `@skip` etc

Comment: Actually, the problem was trivial. I've needed to restart the server and with configuration above it worked... feeling dumb right now. I've also found very helpful this package https://github.com/Valentin-Seehausen/create-react-app now I have problem with relay requiring root node as an object :)